# Which will be more unique?

Tags: php, unique

I need a 16 digit unique number.
 I can use the following 2 examples, Which will generate more unique numbers?

```
<?php>
$a=rand(1000000000000000,9999999999999999);
$b=rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999);
echo($a);
echo($b);
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you test the different methods?

Comment: @Uchiha Does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

The first will generate more random numbers simply because it will allow "0" in 3 additional spots that the second won't.

Comment: Any other method to create 16digit unique ID?Only digits should be there.

Comment: Look at solution c) in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=rand(1000000000000000,9999999999999999);
```

Creates one number in the range from 1000000000000000 to 9999999999999999 which makes a total of **8999999999999999 possible numbers**.

```
$b=rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999).rand(1000,9999);
```

Creates 4 numbers from 1000 to 9999 which makes a total of 8999 * 8999 * 8999 * 8999 = **6558084485964001 numbers**.

First variation will produce about 37% more possible numbers compared with second solution.

This will create one random 16-digit number from 0000000000000000 to 9999999999999999:

```
$c = sprintf('%016d',rand(0,9999999999999999));
```

Answer (score 1):

`$a` is more random for it can have all zeros except at the placement of preceding `1` - whereas `$b` can't.

**But that's not my point**

Your $b statement indicates that your random number can well be a string.

So why not expanding your range by padding zeros to make it still 16 digits?

```
$a = str_pad(rand(0,9999999999999999), 16, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

There are additional 1000000000000000 possibilities here.

Comment: I need a number preferably not a string actually.

Comment: Also it should be a 16 digit one